# In Star Trek, is there any in-universe mention of the redshirt effect or fatality statistics?

Tags: star-trek

A little while ago, I read a novel called "Redshirts" by John Scalzi.  The novel specifically references Star Trek and the redshirt effect - with the statistics and narrative patterns (including fatalities) from Star Trek serving as an in-universe plot point.

> Proving that the ship they're on has the same patterns, and for the same reasons (being in or influenced by the script of a tv show)

This got me wondering... Is there, in any version of Star Trek, some *in-universe* mention of the redshirt effect?  where the characters discuss or reference the fatality statistics among the crew, act superstitious over away missions, or react (whether predicting or denying them) to the kinds of narrative patterns people would react to in real life, but accept in stories?

I know there were a lot of out-of-universe references to, and jokes about, the redshirt effect, but I'm not familiar enough with the stories to recall any in-universe mention.  And the other questions I saw when I looked ask about fatalities, not how they're referenced in-universe - my apologies if I missed this being answered before!